# How to make a button run a function onclick in Nuxt3(Please check the provided code)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, vuejs3, nuxt3

I am trying to render a button in datatables and in that button, when clicked it is supposed to run a function. But I keep getting this error in my browser.
Uncaught ReferenceError: doSomething is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

```
 <script setup lang="ts">
    
    function doSomething() {
      console.log('Something')
    }
      let data = [
        [
          1,
          2,
          3,
          `<button onclick='doSomething()' class='flex flex-row items-center justify-between bg-customCTA py-2 px-4 rounded-lg shadow-lg hover:bg-customLightCTA hover:bg-opacity-90'>Actions &nbsp; <img src='/images/icons/edit.svg'/> </button>`,
        ],
      ];
      
    </script>
    <template>
      <AdminHeader title="Property Listings" />
      <AdminButton text="Create New Listing" />
      <AdminDTable
        :headings="['Title', 'Type', 'Property Status', '']"
        :data="data"
      />
    </template>
    <style lang="scss" scoped>
    // @import 'bootstrap';
    @import 'datatables.net-dt';
    </style>
```

I want that do something function to be run when the button is clicked.
The button is rendered here using datatables.

```
    <script lang="ts" setup>
  import DataTable from "datatables.net-vue3";
  import DataTablesCore from "datatables.net";
  import "datatables.net-responsive";
  //   import DataTablesLib from 'datatables.net';
  DataTable.use(DataTablesCore);
  const props = defineProps({
    headings: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    data: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  });
  const data = props.data;
  const options = {
    responsive: true,
  };
</script>
<template>
  <section class="my-5">
    <DataTable
      :options="options"
      :data="data"
      class="table table-light  shadow-sm rounded table-hover table-striped display font-base mt-5"
    >
      <thead class="my-5 font-bold">
        <tr>
          <th class="font-bold" scope="col" v-for="heading in headings">
            {{ heading }}
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </DataTable>
  </section>
</template>
<style lang="scss">
  @import "datatables.net-dt";
</style>
```